# Help in Converting Small Python Code to PHP

Tags: php, python

please i need some help in converting a python code to a php syntax 
the code is for generating an alphanumeric code using alpha encoding

the code :

```
def mkcpl(x):  
    x = ord(x)  
    set="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"  
    for c in set:  
        d = ord(c)^x  
        if chr(d) in set:  
            return 0,c,chr(d)  
        if chr(0xff^d) in set:  
            return 1,c,chr(0xff^d)  
    raise Exception,"No encoding found for %#02x"%x  


def mkalphadecryptloader(shcode):  
    s="hAAAAX5AAAAHPPPPPPPPa"  
    shcode=list(shcode)  
    shcode.reverse()  
    shcode = "".join(shcode)  
    shcode += "\x90"*((-len(shcode))%4)  
    for b in range(len(shcode)/4):  
        T,C,D = 0,"",""  
        for i in range(4):  
            t,c,d = mkcpl(shcode[4*b+i])  
            T += t << i  
            C = c+C  
            D = d+D  
        s += "h%sX5%sP" % (C,D)  
        if T > 0:  
            s += "TY"  
            T = (2*T^T)%16  
            for i in range(4):  
                if T & 1:  
                    s += "19"  
                T >>= 1  
                if T == 0:  
                    break  
                s += "I"  
    return s+"\xff\xe4"
```

any help would be really appreciated ...

Comment: -1: I think you should explain to us your core problem, so we can help with a solution, instead of having us translate a script you don't understand. We don't work for you.

Comment: You might look into how to make code formatting work for you.  It's not hard.  Just select all the code before you submit and client the little '10101' icon.  Secondly, I'll be snide and tell you that I'm not going to help anybody convert Python to PHP.  It should be the other way around.  Bleach!  :-)  (I don't actually know PHP that well, so I couldn't help you even if I wanted to.)

Comment: well sir, my skills in python is too bad that's why i'm asking an experts here to help me 

i know php but i don't know python and i haven't get the same function that make the same job in php, i only find it in python

i think it's not really hard to anyone know python to help me to make this code in php language 

and my core problem that i need a function in php that doing converting shellcode to alphanumeric code :)

Comment: http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2002/10/11/

Comment: Take half an hour and you shouldn't have a problem with it any more. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 4):

i will help you a little. For the rest of it, please read up on the [documentation](http://www.php.net/docs.php).

```
function mkcpl($x){
    $x=ord($x);
    $set="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $set=str_split($set);
    foreach($set as $c){
        $d=ord($c)^$x;
        if( in_array( chr($d) ,$set ) ){
            return array(0,$c,chr($d));
        }
        if ( in_array( chr(0xff^d) ,$set ) ){
            return array(0,$c,chr(0xff^$d));
        }
    }
}

function mkalphadecryptloader($shcode){
    $s="hAAAAX5AAAAHPPPPPPPPa";
    # you could use strrev()
    $shcode=str_split($shcode);
    $shcode=array_reverse($shcode);
    $shcode=implode("",$shcode);
    # continue on... read the documentation
}

print_r(mkcpl("A"));
mkalphadecryptloader("abc");



Python:                                PHP

len() - length of string/array.        strlen(),count() 
range() - generate range of numbers    for($i=0;$i<=number;$i++)
<<                                     <<
```

the rest of them, like +=, == etc are pretty much the same across the 2 languages.

Answer (score 0):

> the rest of them, like +=, == etc are
>   pretty much the same across the 2
>   languages.

Careful; in PHP string concatenation is accomplished using `.=` not `+=`. If you try to use `+=` PHP will try to evaluate the expression mathematically (probably returning a null) and you'll be pulling your hair out trying to figure out what's wrong with your script.

Comment: Like Sp1der_Net's "answer", the above "answer" should also be a comment. One very good reason is that when you comments on someone's answer, that person will get a notification on every SO page that their answer has received a comment.

Comment: Good call; Thanks. I'm new here, so I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: @outis actually, for the person get notified an answer is **currently** much better than a comment. Both email and RSS focus on showing only answers, and they give no comments at all.

Comment: @Cawas: "Better", in this case, isn't precise enough a term. E-mail notifications and subscribing to the RSS feed of questions require action on part of a user (personally, I don't use either for questions I answer). The response notification when a logged-in user views an SO page, however, requires no action. As a consequence, you could just as easily say the latter is "better".

Comment: @Cawas: In any case, posting a comment to another answer as an answer doesn't follow the SO format (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette). This is a Q&A site after all, and not a forum.

Comment: @outis yes, answers should be answers, and comments should be comments. Not arguing that. I'm just saying that if you want to get in touch with someone, and that person get notified through SO (a lot of users don't provide another method on their profile), answering a question from them will grant better results in general. But it's surely much more appropriate to use comments.